# SWT performance issue in Drawing vs Swing

Tags: performance, swing, swt

### Why SWT draws so slowly compared with AWT?

All,

A classic question but it really surprises me for the difference in numbers.

Attached simple tests in Swing and SWT, drawing text with random fonts 1000 times.

**SWT (gc.advance off)**

~80ms for every 1000 text drawn

**SWT (gc.advance on)**

~200ms for every 1000 text drawn

**Swing (with Anti-aliasing hints on)**

~30ms for every 1000 text drawn

Config:

- Win7
- Java 1.6_25
- SWT org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.7.1.v3738a.jar

Thanks for you all.

SWTTest.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.FontData;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class SWTTest {
    private static Font font;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
    shell.open();
            font = new Font(display, new FontData("Tahoma", (int) (Math.random() * 30), SWT.NORMAL));

    shell.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            drawshit(e.gc);
        }
    });

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }

    font.dispose();
    display.dispose();

    System.in.read();
}

private static void drawshit(Shell shell) {

    if (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        GC gc = new GC(shell);
        Rectangle bounds = shell.getBounds();

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            // try various different things here, e.g. drawing lines, rectangles, cacheing fonts etc.
            // Font font = new Font(gc.getDevice(), new FontData("Tahoma", (int) (Math.random() * 30), SWT.NORMAL));
            gc.setFont(font);
            gc.drawText("Hello World", (int) (Math.random() * 400), (int) (Math.random() * 400));
            font.dispose();
        }
        long stop = System.nanoTime();

        gc.dispose();

        System.out.println("SWT time: " + (stop - start) / 1000000 + " ms");
    }
}
}
```

AWTTest.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

public class AWTTest extends Frame implements MouseListener, WindowListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AWTTest();
}

public AWTTest() {
    /*
     * Label hello = new Label("Hello World"); add(hello, "Center");
     */
    setSize(500, 500);
    setVisible(true);

    addMouseListener(this);
    addWindowListener(this);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    // SWT Default font:
    // [1|Tahoma|8.25|0|WINDOWS|1|-11|0|0|0|400|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|Tahoma]

    g2d.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    g2d.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        // try various different things here, e.g. drawing lines, rectangles, cacheing fonts etc.
        g2d.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, (int) (Math.random() * 30)));
        g2d.drawString("Hello World", (int) (Math.random() * 400), (int) (Math.random() * 400));
    }
    long stop = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("AWT time: " + (stop - start) / 1000000 + " ms");

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    this.paintAll(getGraphics());
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    System.exit(0);
}

@Override
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: **What's the question?** The first thing I notice when reading your code that it is sometimes very faulty. Save resources by creating font objects once, painting events should be implemented in the same way, why has your Swing example a mouse listener built in? According to your main method, you ran both examples one after the other. For better comparison you should start from a clean VM.

Comment: Yes, font and other resources should be cached as much as possible in normal case.  But even with that cache (and tested with clean VM separated) the SWT reading is not positively anyway.

With the font created only once beforehand, **SWT still gives ~60ms, almost 2 times of AWT**, not mentioning gc.advance is still OFF.

We are heavily using SWT at the moment but this small test really confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

As phineas already commented, your SWT code is not good.

But you are also comparing two very different outputs. SWT draws natively, by design. The OS is responsible for drawing, which may yield a very different result than drawing with AWT. Whether you prefer your application to be consistent with other applications of the user's OS is up to you.

Anyway, in your example, the AWT text is simply anti-aliased. The SWT text is drawn by Windows with [ClearType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType). If you disable ClearType (in the Windows settings), the performance of "SWT" is drastically faster (in reality it's the performance of Windows), even though your benchmark has the issues phineas mentioned.

Running your benchmark on another OS will produce different numbers again.

**Update**:

I just used your code, fixed the obvious dispose bug of the current version, added

```
   shell.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
         drawshit(shell);
      }
   });
```

at the end of `drawshit`, and made the font size static, since it is very relevant for performance. I used 15 as size for both classes.

With ClearType enabled `SWTTest` takes about 50 ms, without ClearType takes about 17 ms per iteration. I use WinXP SP3.

`AWTTest` is still way faster with values between 3 ms and 11 ms.

All this only shows, that ClearType is makes drawing of text dramatically slower. That's not SWT's fault, but happens because of the underlying OS. Try that benchmark on a Mac and you'll get completely different results.

Comment: Thanks Duckman.  Tried turn off ClearType but yields not much difference.  

I admit the test code may be too simple.  Would be greatly appreciated if someone could show me a "more fair" test code.

Actually I am heavily using SWT at the moment and really feeling sad for the comparison.